# Running Spring Cloud Dataflow Task in REST with arguments

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I need to run a Spring Cloud DataFlow Task using a Rest call. In addition, through Rest I would like to pass an argument. I'm browsing sample paths on localhost:9393 Dataflow server, but I don't see how you can run the ribbon along with the argument. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the REST API guide of `task executions` in Spring Cloud Data Flow [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-task-executions-launching). This shows an example of how to launch a task with arguments and properties.